# Android google maps v2 mapfragment or mapview inside a fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

hello i am trying to create a little mapview inside a fragment with the api v2 maps . Can anyone help understand how it can be done?

Comment: have you got the solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is pretty vague and is probably outside the purview of Stack Overflow. You should check out the mapdemo sample app that comes with the Google Play Services SDK (see [installation instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code)), particularly the MultiMapDemoActivity, which shows how to use multiple MapFragments.